# Where to define API constraints - in schema or code?

Tags: openapi, jsonschema, api-design

We have a REST API, used by not-too-tech-savvy clients. We define the API using an OpenAPI schema. The question is where should we define the input constraints of the requests: in the schema itself (using `allOf`/`anyOf`/`oneOf`/`not`, which complicates the schema and is potentially hard to understand for clients) or in the code (which requires us to write extensive checks and detailed error messages to explain the problem)?

Arguments for and against (so far):

Constraints in schema:

- (+) Clients can verify their payload before hitting the endpoints.
- (+) Less code on the server side, less chance of bugs.
- (-) JSON Schema constraints can be pretty hard to parse, and thus make the schema harder to understand and use.

Constraints in the code:

- (+) Request schema itself is fairly simple.
- (-) Need to add more documentation around the schema and also add more error response types to the schema.
- (-) Need to add more "manual" validation and error handling in the server side code.